# Krusader will not open gzip archives

Tags: archive, krusader

Krusader will not open gzip archives. Krusader claims it will "transparently handle" gzip, zip and some other archives. I tested a zip archive and Krusader does open the archive and shows the contents; I can browse the zip archive. However, when I try to do the same with a gzip archive, I get a pop up window inviting me the select which program to use to open the archive. It will not open the gzip archive even though it claims that it can and will.

Does anybody know why? I see the Krusader forum is closed due to spamming. Thanks for any help :)

I created the test archive using gzip from the command line and then used the file command to check the file type.

```
$ file  youtube-bowie-13-1-2016.txt.gz
youtube-bowie-13-1-2016.txt.gz: gzip compressed data, was "youtube-bowie-13-1-2016.txt", last modified: Thu Jan 14 12:19:15 2016, from Unix
```

[image: Krusader Archive Handling]

[image: Krusader Pop Up]

About my system:

Ubuntu version: 15.04

Krusader version: 2.4.0-beta3

Comment: Vivid Vervet 15.04 has reached 'End of Life' in February of this year. You will need to upgrade and then see if the issue persists...

Comment: yes, I see that andrew. I am waiting for ubuntu 16 at the end of this month. yes, I will as you suggest wait and see. seems to me this is a long term trouble for krusader in ubuntu; finger's crossed for the upgrade anyhow :)

Comment: Looks like you will encounter the same issue unfortunately, workaround below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you question deals with an EOL Ubuntu release I have found that the same issue exists on Trusty Tahr. A *partial* fix is simple:

1. Right click on the archive from within the Krusader winder
2. Select: Other
3. Select 'Browse'
4. Navigate to `/usr/bin/file-roller` and select this
5. Ensure you have selected the 'Remember Application...' button
6. Click OK

A screenshot below to illustrate the crucial settings:

[image]

You will still not see the gzip file in the Krusader window (the 'Transparent' handling) but you will see it in File Roller. Annoyingly looks like that bug was actually closed as fixed in this version:

- [Bug 306683 - gzip protocol not supported by krusader](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=306683)

Comment: Thank you much for the workaround Andrew. I will be using that. I will accept your solution as I don't forsee a solution in a reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problem with zip archives - despite "zip" options checked in "Archives" configuration tab and zip/unzip programs recognized automatically and available in $PATH, zip archives were not handled by Krusader but opened in external program.

The solution was to add MIME type "application/zip" to "krarc" protocol in "Protocols" configuration tab. This entry should be present but mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: Worked here for 16.04.